# Using 'ignore' argument in hunspell function

Tags: r, hunspell

I'm attempting to exclude some words when running hunspell_check on a text block in Rstudio.

```
ignore_me <- c("Daniel")

hunspell_check(unlist(some_text), ignore = ignore_me, dict = dictionary("en_GB"))
```

However, whenever I run I get the following error:

```
Error in hunspell_check(unlist(some_text, dict = dictionary("en_GB"), : 
  unused argument (ignore = ignore_me))
```

I've had a look around SO and trawled the documenation but am struggling to figure what's gone wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you’ve missed a closing bracket after `some_text`, so it’s passinng `ignore` as an argument to `unlist()` rather than `hunspell_check()`.

UPDATE: Ok, I think you were looking at an old version of the documentation. At least that's what I did at first (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/hunspell/versions/1.1/topics/hunspell_check). In the current version, 2.9, `ignore` is no longer an argument for `hunspell_check()`. Instead, use `add_words` in the call to `dictionary()`:

```r
library(hunspell)

some_text <- list("hello", "there", "Daniell")
hunspell_check(unlist(some_text), dict = dictionary("en_GB"))
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

ignore_me <- "Daniell"
hunspell_check(unlist(some_text), dict = dictionary("en_GB", add_words = ignore_me))
# [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: My mistake, typo is post rather than code - have corrected. Thanks!

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much!